# Tuning app for Android

Tags: android, music

In my case I want to tune my guitar, but the app I'm looking for doesn't (or even shouldn't) have to be only for guitars.

Following are my top requirements:

- Quick start: therefore it should be lightweight, ideally I just want to open my app and then immediatly play the first string on my guitar to tune it, no other functions like metronome and such needed
- Accuracy: it should not wobble around too much (unless of course the sound really wobbles in the human ear), I've had this experience with a couple of apps, so there needs to be a good filter
- Automatic tune detection switch: I should be able to either set a certain note I'm trying to reach or just let it recognize my note automatically without a goal
- free
- Saveable sets of notes, e.g. 6 different notes of a guitar like many apps have but as soon as you want to have a different tuning or even create your own you have to go pro and pay -.-

Don't tell me similar apps because I've tried out many similar apps already, only if you happen to actually know one that meets at least 4 out of my 5 requirements it might be the one I was looking for :)

> Edit: If you think you know a better app, than in the answer feel free to post it. If I think so too, I will mark that as the answer. Otherwise it might still be usable for others who don't have the same requirements as me so I think it would be nice to have a selection of the best tuning apps in the answers as there are many bad ones out there in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, there are a lot of tuning apps which you can try out at Play Store. But I think smartchord is best option, because it offers almost all tools for making playing guitar much easier (chord search, tuner, pitch pipe, scale, metronome, etc).

Comment: Could you include a link to that app? Also it would be nice to point out how it fits the requirements listed in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'll mark this as answered until someone comes up with an even better app - after all this one doesn't fulfill all of my requirements (e.g. first one: tune right after opening the app and it has a loot of features I don't need) but it is definitely one of the better tuning apps I know and it's free so thanks - I'll be using it for now :)